# Dynamically allocate buffer space for a two-dimensional array -- why does this fail?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, types, multidimensional-array

I am amidst C++ multidimensional array pointer hell.  I have a function that takes two pointers to two multi-dimensional arrays.  The function transforms the input array into the output array.

```
void transpose(float * in, float * out) throw() {
  size_t numvars = dataset.getVariables().size()
  size_t numsegs = dataset.getSegments().size();
  ...
```

I am having trouble dynamically allocating the the buffer for the output array.  I thought the following would work because arrays decayed to pointers automatically:

```
size_t numvars = dataset.getVariables().size()
size_t numsegs = dataset.getSegments().size();
float tData[numvars][numsegs];
transpose(data, tData);
```

But I get the error:

> no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘float [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)numvars) + -1)) + 1)][(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)numsegs) + -1)) + 1)]’ to ‘float*’

So why does this fail?  And what's the correct/best way to dynamically allocate size for a 2-dimensional array so the `transpose` function can do its thing?

Comment: Don't use pointers. Use proper data structures and pass them by (const) reference.

Comment: tData is not a float* is it? Hence the error message. Contrary to what you state, transpose does not take pointers to two multidimensional arrays.

Comment: I thought it would be since arrays decay to pointers.  Is that ONLY true for single dimension arrays and NOT for multi dimension arrays?

Comment: An n-dimensional array decays into a pointer to (n-1)-dimensional array. It only "forgets" its first dimension.

Comment: @Brian Bi - that's true for arrays with fixed dimension. `float tData[numvars][numsegs]` is a compiler extension and I do not see what data type `tData` would decay to. `int (*)[numsegs]` is not a type.

Comment: @MattMcNabb ah, you're right, I didn't notice that. I don't actually know how those things behave :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void transpose(float * in, float * out)
...
float tData[numvars][numsegs];
transpose(data, tData);
```

`tData` is of type `float[numvars][numsegs]` which can decay only to `float (*)[numsegs]`.
If `out` expects an address of first element in this 2D array, then you could simply do:

```
transpose(data, &tData[0][0]);
```

i.e.:

```
void foo(float* pF){}

int main()
{
    float f, arr[10], arr2d[5][7];

    foo(&f);            // perfectly straightforward
    foo(arr);           // float[10] decays to float*
    foo(arr2d[0]);      // float[7] decays to float*

    foo(&arr2d[0][0]);  // perfectly straightforward
    foo(arr2d);         // float[5][7] decays to float (*) [7] ~> float* ???
                        // ERROR: can't convert decayed float (*) [7] to float *
}
```

Also note that `float tData[numvars][numsegs];` doesn't "dynamically allocate" an array. It is a variable-length array with automatic storage duration (a.k.a. VLA).

---

However, instead of C-style approach based on pointers, you might consider using `std::vector` :

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<float> > FloatMatrix;

void transpose(const FloatMatrix& in, FloatMatrix& out);
...
FloatMatrix data;
...
FloatMatrix fm = FloatMatrix(numvars, std::vector<float>(numsegs));
transpose(data, fm);
```

Comment: The transpose function knows the size that tData is supposed to be.  I added the code in an edit to show you that.  Yeah, transpose is not really a safe function.  I get that.  Still looking for an answer to my question though.

Comment: @jakeliquorblues: Fair enough. I've edited my answer.

Comment: So data[numvars] implicitly converts to `char *` (or `&data[0]`) but `data[numvars][numsegs]` does not implicitly convert to anything?

Comment: "It is a variable-length array with automatic storage duration (a.k.a. VLA)." - C++ does not have VLAs, they are a C99 thing. OP must be using a compiler extension (and as such, any behaviour involving this array is also part of the compiler extension). AFAIK, in C99 `tData` doesn't decay, and `tData[x]` decays to `float *`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I didn't write that VLAs are part of standard C++.